# upload large javascript object as json file on aws s3 (efficient way)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Hi I have json response probably of size 150-200MB. Because of its size, I want to save it on aws s3 as json file instead of returning it to the client.
Below this the code I m using currently.

```
async function uploadFileOnS3(fileData, s3Detail) {
  const params = {
    Bucket: s3Detail.Bucket,
    Key: s3Detail.Key_response,
    Body: JSON.stringify(fileData), // big fat js object
  };
  try {
    const stored = await S3.upload(params).promise();
    console.log("file uploaded Sucessfully ", stored);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  console.log("upload exit");
}
```

I m concern about  JSON.stringify(fileData) operation. assuming this function will be part of a aws lambda, won't it take huge resources to parse it as string?

is there any other efficient way to save javascript object as json on aws s3 bucket?

Answer (score 0):

You don't really have to stringify the JSON file. You can pass a stream as a body:

```
async function uploadFileOnS3(fileData, s3Detail) {
    const params = {
        Bucket: s3Detail.Bucket,
        Key: s3Detail.Key_response,
        Body: fileData, // remove stringify from here
    };
    try {
        const stored = await S3.upload(params).promise();
        console.log("file uploaded Sucessfully ", stored);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("upload exit");
}

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // We create a stream
    const stream = fs.createReadStream("/tmp/upload.json");

    // Pass the stream to the upload function
    await uploadFileOnS3(stream, {
        Bucket: "bucket_name",
        Key_response: "upload.json"
    });
}
```